# Random table sampling query in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I can write your typical "SELECT A,C FROM B WHERE B.id = 10" query, but have otherwise made very little use of SQL, and what I need to do with this query is well beyond my SQL experience at this point.

I have a table T with primary key Tid and a special column S in SQLite. I want to create another table which is a single column made up of values of Tid. I need my new table to have 1000 random values of Tid for EACH possible value of S.

So if I was to group T by S then my new table would represent 1000 random principle keys from each group.

What SQLlite query will create such a table?

Note: Table T is huge, so better performing queries are better.

Comment: You say you want to make a new ***table*** but this would result in large data duplication. Do you mean a query? And a concrete example, using small values, would make this question clearer. Finally, how "huge" is "huge"? Hundreds? Thousands? Millions? (getting huge) Billions?

Comment: Huge in this case is up to hundreds of millions. Though if I end up needing to do the same thing on different table, it could be more. Computation time is far more valuable to me than disk space in this matter, so storing the results in a table is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: I came up with a simpler solution than my first one.

First, we create a table to put the result in:

```
CREATE TABLE result(tid integer primary key, s);
```

At the end of this process, `result` will contain 1000 rows from each group of each unique `s` value from the original table `t`.

The basic idea is to create a "magic" special view with one column `s`, that has the property that each time we try to insert any value of `s` into it, instead, 1000 random rows from `t` that have the same value for `s` will be selected and inserted into `result`. We can do that with a trigger:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW result_view AS SELECT null AS s WHERE 0;

CREATE TEMP TRIGGER result_ins_trigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON result_view FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO result(tid, s)
    SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.s=NEW.s ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1000;
END;
```

Now that we have that view, we try to insert all distinct values of `s` into it and the trigger will do the rest:

```
INSERT INTO result_view SELECT DISTINCT s FROM t;
```

Note that the process will be significantly faster if you have an index on `t(s)`, so might want to create that first (and then drop it if you don't need it).

Essentially, the above solution is a poor man's implementation of `LATERAL` subqueries, using triggers.

---

**Original answer**: Here's a solution that uses a temporary trigger. First, we create a table to put the result in:

```
CREATE TABLE result(tid integer primary key, s, num NOT NULL);
```

At the end of this process, `result` will contain 1000 rows from each group of each unique `s` value from the original table `t`. The table also has an auxiliary column called `num`. Then we do the following:

```
CREATE INDEX result_s_idx ON result(s, num);

CREATE TEMP VIEW result_view AS SELECT null AS TID, null AS s, NULL AS num WHERE 0;

CREATE TEMP TRIGGER result_ins_trigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON result_view FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO result(tid, s, num)
    SELECT NEW.tid, NEW.s,
           COALESCE((SELECT max(num) FROM result WHERE s=NEW.s),0)+1 AS num
    WHERE num<=1000;
END;

INSERT INTO result_view(tid, s, num)
SELECT tid,s,null FROM t ORDER BY random();

DROP INDEX result_s_idx;
```

The idea is to try insert everything from `t` into `result`, in a random order, assigning to each row a number (stored in the column `num`) that indicates what is the position (in the random order) of that element within that group. So e.g. if `num` is 11, then that means that row is the 11th row of that group. Additionally, if the number becomes larger than 1000 then we discard the row, because we only need 1000 rows per group. In order to impelemt the previous logic, we use a trigger so that for each row that we try to insert, it runs a subquery to calculate the right value of `num` and discards the row if `num` is greater than 1000. Because sqlite does not allow `INSTEAD OF` triggers on regular tables, we create that trigger on a dummy temporary view. Finally, we insert all the row from `t` into the dummy view (so that the trigger kicks in) in a random order.

Essentially, the above solution is a poor man's implementation of the `row_number` window function, using triggers.

One last issue, is the auxiliary column `num` of `result`. If you are bothered by it, it can be removed by creating a new table without it and copying all data from `result`.

Comment: @JohnRobertson I am afraid I have no reference to recommend. In this instance, I just tried to think of how I would solve this problem in postgresql and then I tried to translate the solution to sqlite.

Comment: @rednab Some time has elapsed now since you answered this question. Rarely do I feel more impressed with an answer as time passes. This is one of those answers that I reflect on and feel like I am learning more from it over time, as it is a better way of thinking about accomplishing things in SQL than I am acquainted with. Thank you for posting it.